# Result of operation not being assigned to variable?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a strange problem in C++, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but cannot figure out what.

The purpose of the function is to set some bits of a variable. From my tests, it all seems to work however it looks like the result of the operation is not assigned back to the variable.

```
uint16_t setBits(uint16_t target, unsigned int source, int offset, int bitCount) {
    unsigned int mask = ~0;
    mask = mask >> ((sizeof(mask) * 8) - bitCount);
    int rightShift = (sizeof(mask) * 8 - bitCount - offset);
    mask = mask << rightShift;
    source = source << rightShift;
    printHex(target);
    printHex((target & ~mask) | (source & mask));
    target = (target & ~mask) | (source & mask);
    printHex(target);
    return target;
}

uint16_t group;
group = 0xabcd;
unsigned int source = 0x12;
group = setBits(group, source, 4, 8);
```

This would print:

```
0x0000abcd
0x0120abcd
0x0000abcd
```

Which for me means that `(target & ~mask) | (source & mask)` gives the correct result (0x0120abcd), however this result is not assigned back to `target` (which is still set to 0x0000abcd). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `target` has a 16 bit type.

Comment: you should add a check for this value also `unsigned int source, int offset, int bitCount` ,  where is `target has a 16 bit type` look main mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the type for `target`:

```
uint16_t target
```

It's only 16 bits, but you try to mask in bits higher than that.

Comment: and solution is `mask` and `rightshift` should be `uint16_t` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan _If_ a 16-bit value is wanted. If a 32-bit value is wanted then the type of `target` needs to be changed.

Comment: Yes for this reason I generally do this kind stuff in MACRO.